# WPF - Combobox with button in ItemTemplate, click on SelectedItem

Tags: wpf, button, combobox, wpf-controls

I have a combobox with a list of entries+actions as text and button:

```
[ Item #1 [Preview] v ]
| Item #2 [Preview]   |
| Item #3 [Preview]   |
| Item #4 [Preview]   |
```

The problem is user can only click buttons on the drop-down list, but not on selected item. Basically any click on ComboCox causes drop-down opened.

Is there any way to limit drop-down to only V button? Or somehow else make buttons in the selected item clickable?

Here is my XAML

```xml
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding LayoutsList}" >
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                <Button 
                    Command="{Binding PreviewCommand}" 
                    CommandParameter="{Binding}"
                    >Preview</Button>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that may only be possible with overwriting the entire `ComboBox.Template`. The dropdown appears on MouseDown, and it seems to cancel any subsequent event handlers inside the item, such as your `Button.Click` event, so I don't think there's a way around it other than to override the Template.

As an alternative, you could try using the `PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown` to determine if the mouse is over the [Preview] button, and if so set `e.Handled = true` and show the Preview of the `SelectedItem`. I don't know of an easy way to do that though, and am not sure if investigating this route is worth it.